# Macbook pro - mid 2012 screen going black

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, error, kernel-panic

My screen keeps going black as if it is going to sleep but will then not wake up, no matter how many various key combinations i retry.

I get the following stack trace upon restart which makes it look like there is potentially something wrong with the video card driver? Some suggestions would be much appreciated because my macbook is out of warranty now and i guess it will cost me a lot to get repaired :(

```
Anonymous UUID:       9E17DAD1-B81B-68B9-68CA-ABE2762E248A


Wed Dec 10 19:58:41 2014
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f853f7f7c): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 4 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x102c00000 0xffffff81148e8000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.6.22/src/Apple MuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81141db530 : 0xffffff8003022f79
0xffffff81141db5b0 : 0xffffff7f853f7f7c
0xffffff81141db680 : 0xffffff7f83b67ba4
0xffffff81141db740 : 0xffffff7f83c31ebe
0xffffff81141db780 : 0xffffff7f83c31f2e
0xffffff81141db7f0 : 0xffffff7f83e669de
0xffffff81141db860 : 0xffffff7f83c549e5
0xffffff81141db880 : 0xffffff7f83b6e65d
0xffffff81141db930 : 0xffffff7f83b6c168
0xffffff81141dbb30 : 0xffffff7f83b6d208
0xffffff81141dbc10 : 0xffffff7f83b1b5b1
0xffffff81141dbdb0 : 0xffffff7f83b1a21a
0xffffff81141dbdd0 : 0xffffff7f853c968c
0xffffff81141dbeb0 : 0xffffff7f853c9568
0xffffff81141dbf00 : 0xffffff7f853c820e
0xffffff81141dbf20 : 0xffffff800304a20a
0xffffff81141dbfb0 : 0xffffff80030d7607
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.6.22)[32862231-50BC-3AF6-87A2-703321AE4F90]@ 0xffffff7f853e9000->0xffffff7f853fcfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.6.22)[AA46D551-BE0F-33DA-93A3-8F46197BB 36F]@0xffffff7f853e1000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xfffff f7f84432000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff 7f836bf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0 xffffff7f83abe000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[80899285-3952-30DA-A0F9-357C51E104 CF]@0xffffff7f853e4000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[272B6397-FEDB-32FC-9035-BDD749284455] @0xffffff7f83b17000->0xffffff7f83d8afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff 7f836bf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xff ffff7f83b01000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0 xffffff7f83abe000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.6.22)[91D61DEC-2946-3790-8134-B808C016C4 C9]@0xffffff7f83b11000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(8.2.6)[EF73AF59-A574-3A5A-B410-7E4F2DA819B 0]@0xffffff7f83d96000->0xffffff7f83f42fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(8.2.6)[272B6397-FEDB-32FC-9035-BDD749284455] @0xffffff7f83b17000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff 7f836bf000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.14.34)[B40DF46A-AA80-39C2-BBC6-DA5DF93509AC]@0xffffff 7f853c6000->0xffffff7f853d8fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff 7f836bf000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.7.1d6)[67BEDCC9-E9AB-3F32-82CE-84729F B82C0A]@0xffffff7f8443b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xff ffff7f83b01000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0 xffffff7f83abe000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.6.22)[91D61DEC-2946-3790-8134-B808C016C4 C9]@0xffffff7f83b11000


BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task


Mac OS version:
13F34


Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8003000000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)


System uptime in nanoseconds: 18318862975
last loaded kext at 6922148357: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 4.3.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8555e000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 4.3.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt 4.3.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.0
com.Cycling74.driver.WondershareAudioDevice 1.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy 3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.34
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.0.9d7
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs 3.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 4.2.7f3
com.apple.GeForce 8.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics 8.2.8
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup 8.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 683.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC 1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 153
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 217.92.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.6.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.23
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 8.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman 8.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.6.22
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f3
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 98.23
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox 278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f35
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news? Your GPU is faulty. Good news? Apple launched a [repair program](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) to fix MacBook Pro machines sold between February 2011 and February 2013 that have problems with distorted video, no video, or unexpected system restarts.

(taken from [macrumors.com](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/02/19/2011-macbook-pro-repair-program-apple/))

Comment: Hi Francesco, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thank you so much - i had a very expensive paper weight sitting there after apple shop told me it would cost almost more than a replacement!

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when you're using the integrated graphics (when running solely on battery power)?

My advice would be to perform an SMC reset then see what happens. If the problem persists get hold of a USB hard disk and install a clean copy of OS X on it, then see if you get exactly the same issue when the system goes to sleep.

If you do have the same problem it will point to a hardware issue, possibly a GPU re-ball/re-flow (a pain but ultimately a lot cheaper than buying a new or even secondhand MacBook).

And, if you don't have any problems, you can simply back up using Time Machine, erase your drive and reinstall - at a cost of nothing except time taken.

Comment: I think the issue is when it switches to the graphics cards from the integrated on board graphics - this is the trend i have spotted especially when watching movies and so forth, is there a way i can tell it to stop using the other graphics card from the command line some how ?

Comment: Try running purely on the discrete graphics and see what happens - go to Energy Saver and turn off the Automatic Graphics Switching option. In my experience the nVidia card on my MacBook doesn't use much more juice than the integrated Intel graphics for everyday tasks (anything that's not GPU-intensive). It'll be interesting to see what happens...